# Batch file keeps closing if i choose variable 2

Tags: batch-file, adb

I am currently making my own ADB toolkit menu on batch
so i got ahead and tested the batch file but it always quitting the batch file if i choose the variable 2. what should i do?

```
@echo off
:MENU
cls
title ADB TOOLKIT
echo.
echo.
echo                                              ----------------------------
echo                                              ADB TOOLKIT MADE BY TECHDARK
echo                                              ----------------------------
echo.                            
echo.
echo ----------------------------------------------------
echo 1) Install APK
echo 2) Unlock phone
echo 3) Lock phone
echo ----------------------------------------------------
set /p select=type 1,2 or 3
if %select%==1 goto install
if %select%==2 goto unlock
if %select%==3 goto lock

:install
cls
echo What do you want to install?
set /p Input=Type in apk:
cls
echo installing...
echo.
adb install "apps\%Input%"
pause
goto menu

:lock
cls
adb shell input keyevent 26
cls
echo Your phone is locked!
pause
goto menu

:unlock
cls
echo Do your phone have a password or PIN
set /p pswd==(y/n)
if %pswd%==y goto pswdunlock
if %pswd%==n goto nopswdunlock
pause

:nopswdunlock
cls
adb shell input keyevent 26
cls
echo Your phone is locked!
pause
goto menu

:pswdunlock
cls
echo What is your PIN/Password?
set /p PIN=Type PIN/Pswd here:
cls
echo unlocking
echo.
adb shell input keyevent 26 && adb shell input keyevent 1 && adb shell input text %PIN% && adb shell input keyevent 66
pause
goto menu
```

Comment: What should you do you say?  Learn to properly debug your script.  First rules of debugging a batch file is to turn `ECHO ON` at the top of your script and open up a command prompt and execute the batch file directly from the command prompt instead of using your mouse.  You will then see exactly what line the script is having problems which in your case the error is: `C:\Batch>set /p pswd==(y/n)
The syntax of the command is incorrect.` Do you see the problem with the `SET` command? Look at all your other `SET` commands.  What is different?

Comment: WOOPS lol added two equals signs man, i've been trying to find the error for almost two hours now lol God i am stupid   thanks you though

Comment: Usually when the code is a typo it will get flagged for closure.  You have the option to delete your question, which I would advise you do.

Comment: well, @Squashman already pointed out your issue, but why not rather use the `choice` command here? see `choice /?`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following shorter code for the task:

```bat
@echo off

:menu
cls

title ADB TOOLKIT
echo.
echo.
echo   ----------------------------
echo   ADB TOOLKIT MADE BY TECHDARK
echo   ----------------------------
echo.
echo.
echo ---------------
echo 1) Install APK
echo 2) Unlock phone
echo 3) Lock phone
echo ---------------

choice /c:123 /M "Type 1, 2 or 3: " /N
cls

if errorlevel 3 goto lock
if errorlevel 2 goto unlock
if errorlevel 1 goto install

:install
echo What do you want to install?
set /p "install=Type in apk: "
cls
echo Installing...
echo.
adb install "apps\%install%"
pause
goto menu

:lock
adb shell input keyevent 26
cls
echo Your phone is locked!
pause
goto menu

:unlock
choice /C:yn /M "Does your phone have a password or PIN? "

if errorlevel 2 goto nopswdunlock
if errorlevel 1 goto pswdunlock

pause

:nopswdunlock
cls
adb shell input keyevent 26
cls
echo Your phone is locked!
pause
goto menu

:pswdunlock
cls
set /p "PIN=What is your PIN/Password? Type here: "
cls
echo Unlocking, please wait...
echo.
adb shell input keyevent 26 && adb shell input keyevent 1 && adb shell input text %PIN% && adb shell input keyevent 66
pause
goto menu
```

See `choice /?` and `set /?` for info about what do command used here do.